# How do I get parent and siblings of ElementHandle in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I have a ElementHandle, and not its selector, how do I get its Parent and Siblings as ElementHandle.

I know that given selector of the Element, it can be done using

```
const item = document.querySelector(query);
const parent = item.parentElement;
```

Don't know what to do if I have ElementHandle instead of its selector. Please help.

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`elementHandle.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlexexpression) to evaluate an XPath expression relative to the [`elementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) to obtain the parent and siblings of your given element:

```
const example = await page.$('#example'); // Element
const example_parent = (await example.$x('..'))[0]; // Element Parent
const example_siblings = await example.$x('following-sibling::*'); // Element Siblings
```

Answer (score 9):

Although this question is tagged `puppeteer`, it comes up first in Google for similar searches with "Playwright".

For those who are using Playwright, you can use a similar solution (adopted from the [answer provided by @grant-miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52189574/114558)):

```
const example = await page.$('#example'); // Element
const example_parent = await example.$('xpath=..'); // Element Parent
const example_grandparent = await example.$('xpath=../..'); // Element Grandparent
const example_siblings = await example.$$('xpath=following-sibling::*'); // Element Siblings
```

Comment: Dear me, thanks for writing this. It came up today in my Google search. 

Answer (score 4):

Just try this

```
const parent_node = await child_node.getProperty('parentNode')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: what about siblings? i have try this elementHandle.getProperty("nextSibling").asElement() but seems dont work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const parentElement = await exampleElement.evaluateHandle(
    (element) => element?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement,
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.